# I am using Authorize.net payment gateway and doing transaction through Direct Post Method,is it possible to just validate card information

Tags: java, payment-gateway, authorize.net

I am using Authorize.net payment gateway and doing the transaction through Direct Post Method where I don't get Credit card details on my server.Is there anyway where I can just validate the credit/debit card details ,I don't want to charge a customer or even if I charge minimal cost say $1 it should be refunded automatically after validation.

Following is my code :

```
<form id='secure_redirect_form_id' action='https://test.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll' method='POST'> 
<br />

<input type='hidden' name='x_invoice_num' value='<%=System.currentTimeMillis()%>' />
<input type='hidden' name='x_relay_url' value="${relayResponeURL}" /> 
<input type='hidden' name='x_login' value="${paymentModel.paymentLoginId}" />
<input type='hidden' name='x_fp_sequence' value="${sequence}" />
<input type='hidden' name='x_fp_timestamp' value="${timestamp}" />
<input type='hidden' name='x_fp_hash' value="${fingerPrint}" />
<input type='hidden' name='x_version' value='3.1' />
<input type='hidden' name='x_method' value='CC' />
<input type='hidden' name='x_type' value='AUTH_CAPTURE' />
<input type='hidden' name='x_amount' value="${paymentModel.amount}"/>
<input type='hidden' name='x_show_form' value='PAYMENT_FORM' />
<input type='hidden' name='x_test_request' value='FALSE' />
<input type='hidden' name='notes' value="${paymentModel.description}" />

<input type="hidden" name="x_address" value="${location.address1} ${location.address2}" >
<input type="hidden" name="x_city" value="${location.city}" >
<input type="hidden" name="x_state" value="${location.state}" >
<input type="hidden" name="x_email" value="${user.email}" >
<input type="hidden" name="x_email_customer" value="true" >
<input type="hidden" name="x_first_name" value="${user.firstName}" >
<input type="hidden" name="x_last_name" value="${user.lastName}" >
<input type="hidden" name="x_phone" value="${merchant.phoneNumber}" >
<input type="hidden" name="x_zip" value="${location.zipcode}" >
<input type="hidden" name="x_company" value="${merchant.companyName}" >

 <input type='submit' name='buy_button' value='BUY' /> 
 </form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do an AUTH_ONLY which will get authorization for the charge but never actually charge it unless you then run a CAPTURE transaction.

```
<input type='hidden' name='x_type' value='AUTH_CAPTURE' />
```

Keep in mind that effectively freezes those funds on the user's card so you need to either do it for a small amount ($0.00 if your processor supports it, or $0.01) or VOID the transaction immediately after running it.